# Request User's Current Location Watch OS2

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, apple-watch, cllocation, watchos-2

I'm trying to get a fix on the user's current location tied into displaying some data on a Map. My code is as follows for my watch kit extension.

```
   import Foundation
    import CoreLocation

    class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

        override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
            super.awakeWithContext(context)
            // Configure interface objects here.
        }

        override func willActivate() {
            // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
            super.willActivate()
        }

        override func didDeactivate() {
            // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
            super.didDeactivate()
        }



        func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
          dLog("Did get a location.")
        }

        func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
            dLog("Did fail to retrieve a location.")
        }

        func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
            print(status)
        }

        @IBAction func btnRequestLocation() {
            let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestLocation()
        }
```

I've also made sure to include the CoreLocation framework under the WatchKit extension Target Linked Frameworks and Libraries. However, running this code on both the watch simulator and a real Apple watch paired with an iOS app, these delegate callbacks never get fired. I'm not sure if I'm missing a step somewhere that would be preventing me from getting the location. I've tried resetting the location and privacy and I even get the request that my app needs location permissions. I hit "Allow" but no location is ever sent to the Apple Watch extension. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I've also taken some additional steps for iOS 9.

Project -> iOS Target -> Background Modes
- Location Updates is checked
- iOS Target also includes the "Required Background Modes" key in the plist file.

Here is the property list for the iOS App.

[image]

**UPDATE**
Seems this might be a common problem isolated in watch OS2.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14828

Comment: I have same issue when calling these functions in ExtensionDelegate. I realised though that doing the same in InterfaceController it works. See my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33594082/watchkit-corelocation-issue

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting `requestAlwaysAuthorization` so you need to make sure you have enabled Locations background mode and also set `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates=TRUE` (for iOS9).

However, I would recommend requesting `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` instead since you are just calling for a onetime location update via `requestLocation()`.

Comment: I've modified my answer but I'm still unable to retrieve the user location based on your answer. However, the watchKit subset of CLLocationManager does not have access to the allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates property. This seems to be accessible on the iOS side.